# MayaBench (rendering) only using 25% CPU; Other software uses 100%

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, rendering, maya

I have a

```
Intel 2600K 3.4Ghz OC @ 4.8Ghz
ASRock Z68 Extreme 4 Mobo
16GB 1600mhz DDR3 memory.
```

When I run MayaBench for rendering, I get this weird bumpy pattern.

[image: With MayaBench]

while other software (such as the Intel Burn Test)

[image: With other programs]

are fully capable of putting "the hurt" on my machine.

The biggest problem, is that MayaBench is written in a manner to eat every last gob of horsepower available on a system.   What am I doing wrong? Other 2600K processors are able to run 100% with MayaBench.

Using RenderPal software to manage MayaBench operations.

Comment: I would assume this would be a bug in MayaBench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue with Maya.  Maya has a setting in which it refuses to use more then 25% of our system, unless you specifically tell it otherwise.